# What software can detect the parts of speech of written text?

Tags: grammar, software, academic

What software or online tools can detect the parts of speech in a piece of written text (e.g. to predict if a word is a verb, adjective, etc.)?

Comment: very very useful question. i had never thought of doing that, but now i can't see how i lived without it all this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had good results with the [Stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml).

Comment: Please include a link =).

Comment: It is the first result on Google here!

Comment: I've added the link to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is a web demo system called [ICTCLAS](http://ictclas.org/ictclas_demo.html) (Institute of Computing Technology, Chinese Lexical Analysis System). It was developed by the Institute of Computing Technology, Chinese Academy of Science.

There is also a web demo system from [THULAS](http://nlp.csai.tsinghua.edu.cn/thulac/) (Tsinghua University - Lexical Analyzer for Chinese), which was developed by the Nature Language Processing Group, Tsinghua University.

NOTE: I don't know (and I cannot test) whether these site can be accessed freely across the world. 
NOTE2: As with any software language tool, take the results with a grain of salt, they aren't perfect.

Comment: Both links do not seem to work.

Comment: @Village: Oh my god, I'm sorry for that ...

Comment: Oh, the first one is working now. Maybe I just need to wait for the other to work.

Comment: @Village Really ... I cannot access the first now. I'll keep an eye on it. The first one has also a downloadable demo version.

Answer (score 0):

just write the word on google, then type definition after example: run definition   Then a big box with the definition will appear, usually the first one shows what part of speech it is

Answer (score 0):

Update:

[Tencent NLP](http://nlp.qq.com)
[image: Tencent NLP]

[Bonson NLP](http://bosonnlp.com)
[image]

There are many lexical analyzers for Chinese, but these are not developed for daily use, the typical usage is Chinese searcher engine.

I found 
[语言云](http://www.ltp-cloud.com/demo/) has a online demo, I test it by enter a sentence from today news,

"北京时间2月27日凌晨1点，FIFA特别代表大会选举中，因凡蒂诺击败萨尔曼、阿里王子、尚帕涅，成功当选新任国际足联主席，瑞士人的任期至2019年。"

The default result seems complicate, I deselected "语义依存分析" and "语义角色标注".

[image]
[image]
[image]

These tool can not be 100% accurate, for example, "选举" in the sentence is
a noun, not verb ( so the SBV relation is also wrong, SBV means subject-verb),
the biggest mistake is it split 因凡蒂诺(Sorry, Mr.Infantino) to 因 and 凡蒂诺.

These errors are understandable, it is still helpful.

Comment: Updated/better link: http://ltp.ai/demo.html